# Using a loop to extract values of lists within lists in R

Tags: r, list, loops, for-loop, lapply

I have a list (*chla_vals*) containing 12 monthly values of chlorophyll for two lakes (so 24 total chla values). It's important to note that when I use `length()` to check the length of this list, the result is 12. It's because of this that I believe this is a list of lists.

some helpful folks on here had a vaguely similar situation, so I adapted their code to extract the chla values for the first lake using:

`chl_lake1 <- sapply(chla_vals, '[', 1)`

Although this works great, I have multiple lists similar to *chla_vals* that contain slightly different values based on the method used to measure chlorophyll-a, and in the future I will have more lakes. I am therefore trying to write a loop, that will extract these chl-a values for each month and each lake and output them into a dataframe.

I figured the best way to do this, was to combine all my lists (eg: *chla_vals*, *chla_vals1*, *chla_vals2*) into another list, and loop over it. I am a beginner in R so if this is not best practices please let met know.

My code so far:

```
#Reproducible examples of chla_vals, chla_vals2, and chla_vals3
chla_vals <- list(runif(2))
chla_vals <- rep(chla_vals, 12)

chla_vals2 <- list(runif(2))
chla_vals2 <- rep(chla_vals2, 12)

chla_vals3 <- list(runif(2))
chla_vals3 <- rep(chla_vals3, 12)

#Combining all lists into a larger list, and specifying the list names
chla_comb <- list(chla_vals = chla_vals, chla_vals2 = chla_vals2, chla_vals3 = chla_vals3)

#Storing the names of each list  
list_names <- names(chla_comb)

#Creating an empty dataframe to store my values, with 3 columns corresponding to my three original lists
#I know I will need more columns (eg: chlorophyll-a method, month, and lake ID), but I figure I can sort that later
values_df <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(ncol = length(list_names))), list_names)

#The actual loop:
for (i in seq_along(chla_comb)) {
     v <- chla_comb[i]
    values_df[i] <- lapply(v, '[', 1)
  }
```

This kind of works, but is only storing the two first values in each list (ie the chl-a value for lake 1 january, and the value for lake 2 january) for each chl-a method (*chla_vals*, *chla_vals1*, and *chla_vals2*). I need all 24 values for each method as i'm interested in the change in chlorophyll over time

EDIT: Included a small reproducible example. This is the best I could create but the lists don't look exactly like what I have. I think solutions will work either way.

[image]

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example for testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `c` to combine the lists into one and with `do.call(rbind)` convert it into a 2 column matrix.

```
values_mat <- do.call(rbind, c(chla_vals, chla_vals2, chla_vals3))
values_mat

#           [,1]      [,2]
# [1,] 0.1264052 0.1575803
# [2,] 0.1264052 0.1575803
# [3,] 0.1264052 0.1575803
# [4,] 0.1264052 0.1575803
# [5,] 0.1264052 0.1575803
# [6,] 0.1264052 0.1575803
# [7,] 0.1264052 0.1575803
#...
#...
```

Comment: hmm i like this idea, but I lose the list names (chla_vals, chla_vals2, etc). Is there a way to preserve those headers so they appear in the first column? thanks!

Comment: @seak23 You can use `purrr::map_df(chla_comb, ~as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, .)), .id = 'name')`